# How to fix this code - not showing any output

Tags: javascript, html

he code runs but I think that it can't access the spreadsheet/can't find it

I've tried transforming the path, but it doesn't work

```html
<input type="text" name="searchPhrase" />

    <a href="javascript: searchExcel();">Search</a>

    <div id="results" style="margin-bottom: 20px"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function searchExcel()
{
    alert('You clicked the top text');
    var searchPhrase = document.getElementById('searchPhrase').value;
    var Worksheet = 'example.xls';
    var Excel = new ActiveXObject('Excel.Application');

    Excel.Visible = false;
    var Excel_file = Excel.Workbooks.Open(Worksheet, null, true, null,
        "abc", null, true, null, null, false, false, null, null, null);

    var range = Excel_file.ActiveSheet.Range('A:A');
    var jsRangeArray = new VBArray(range.Value).toArray();

    var found = false;
    for(cells in jsRangeArray)
    {
        if(jsRangeArray[cells] == searchPhrase)
        {
           document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Found";
           found = true;
        }
    }

    if(found == false)
    {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Not Found";
    }

    Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(true);
    Excel.Application.Quit();
    Excel = null;
}
    </script>
```

So if for example someone inputs their name and it is in the excel spreadsheet show true.

Comment: What browser are you trying to do this in?

Comment: I tried in Internet Explorer and Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You use `getElementById` but `searchPhrase` input does not have any id.